# Every X results form a string of data?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I have a List with over 1000 unique entries and I want to form out of it, sets of 50 entries into a single string to use on a webclient request.

Here is what I came up with:

```
string query = string.Empty;
for (int i = 0; i < queryList.Count; i++)
{
    query += queryList[i] + Environment.NewLine;
    if (i % 40 == 1)
    {
        // Send webclient request
        query = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Since 1 is also multiple it will trigger at result 1 (not sure how to circumvent and yet send the 2 initial values) after that it works just fine but I was wondering if there is a better approach to make this set of strings to use on the webrequest ?

Also when it gets out of the for I have to send manually the last string as it would if the count total is not a multiple of it, it wont trigger at the end so once it gets out of the for I will have the remains of what left to be sent.

Comment: you can use MoreLinq.Batch, and MoreLinq.Pipe method.

Comment: @Tilak would u mind posting an sample ? Seems interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [MoreLinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/)

[MoreLinq.Batch](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/Batch.cs) -> Divide the collection into batches.

[MoreLinq.Pipe](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/Pipe.cs) -> Similar to Select, allows to do method call

Following query will divide queryList into batch of 40, and then prints 40 items a time (similar to logic in question).

For webclient request, replace Console.WriteLine to webclient request call.

```
queryList.Batch(40).Pipe(x=>Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, x.ToArray()))).ToArray();
```

Comment: +1 That looks really interesting the batch and pipe, but would the performance here against my method be noticeable at all ?

Comment: loop performance will be similar. Yours is most efficient. But with use of [yield](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx) Keyword, unnecessary temp data is not emitted. Click on the links (in answer) to know more

Comment: Thanks I was actually checking it right after I asked the question hehe.

Answer (score 1):

Just add another check block..

```
    if (i % 40 == 1)
    {
        if (i == 1)
            continue;
        // Send webclient request
        query = string.Empty;
    }
```

Comment: +1 Good point, overlooked that, but is my method OK, or were there better approach to my problem ? I am not sure but it doesn't really look well.

Comment: I would do `if ((i > 1) && (i % 40 == 1))`

Comment: @Guapo yours is ok for when it gets bigger. but if it is a simple thing like skipping #1, i would use mine

Comment: Only problem with this is that I would exceed the amount permit per query which is 40 entries.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the build-in [GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby.aspx) to build the payloads.

```
var data = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000)
    .Select(value => value.ToString());

var payloads = data
    .Select((value, idx) => new {idx, value})

    // Abuse automatic integer division cut off.
    .GroupBy(x => x.idx/40)

    // Transform every group into a concatenated string built
    // from all entries in that group.
    .Select(g => g.Aggregate(String.Empty, (curr, next) => curr + next.value + Environment.NewLine));

foreach (var payload in payloads) {
    // Send payload to webservice.
}
```

Comment: Looks pretty interesting and without having to load more references but same question goes what about performance on this method compared to the one I am currently using, would it be noticeable ? My biggest list is 10k entries so nothing much of a problem.

Comment: I would say that you would get the same performance from doing this, compared to what you already have, if your list is already loaded into memory. However, if your list is lazily loaded from a source, then the call to GroupBy will read it into memory causing a higher memory usage than other methods presented. Also, this method wont work if you have an endless list (like a method that yields items forever).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, the list is already loaded before I iterate with it.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer to use something Microsoft backed, how about using [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx) rather than MoreLinq?

You just need `Buffer` and `Do` (combined with `ToObservable()` and then back with `ToEnumerable()`):

```
queryList.ToObservable()
         .Buffer(40).Do(x => Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, x.ToArray())))
         .ToEnumerable().ToArray();
```

Comment: Really nice love the extra knowledge, I still have not decided on which method I will be using but will try all of the ones listed here.